# Standard deviation of inverse of a measure

Tags: homework-and-exercises, error-analysis

I have a measure of a quantity, x, and I know the standard deviation of the measure, STDx.
I want to compute the inverse of x, which is y= 1/x, but then what would happen to the standard deviation?
How can I compute STDy?
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard combination of errors formula gives the answer

$\sigma^2_y=\left( {\partial y \over \partial x}\right) ^2 \sigma_x^2$

which in this case gives $\sigma_y= {1 \over x^2} \sigma_y$

This agrees with @Farcher's answer, but shows where it comes from.

Caution! Only valid for 'small' errors. Otherwise distributions become non-Gaussian.  Use near $x=0$ will void your warranty.

Answer (score 0):

The percentage error stays the same.

For example, if $x = 2.0\pm 0.1 \Rightarrow x=2.0\pm 5\%$

$\dfrac 1x = 0.500\pm 5\% \Rightarrow 0.50\pm 0.025$